# Dots in Filenames and Using Require

Tags: node.js, express

What is this format:

Actual file -- `foo.service.js`

Code -- `require('fooService')`

I see this in people's code. How does require know to get that filename with the dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require()` has some special logic for how it processes the name you give it.  You can see the entire logic [here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

Per that logic, the only way I know of that `require('fooService')` could end up loading `foo.service.js` is if one of the following was true:

1. `fooService.js` is a module that when loaded it then requires `foo.service.js`.
2. `fooService` is a directory that contains a package.json file that references `foo.service.js`.
3. `fooService` is a directory that contains an index.js file that itself loads `foo.service.js`.